# 0x Pricing Issues

Tags: 0x

When using the 0x API to price USDC->DAI on ETH and Polygon, I am getting weird outputs.

When I price the slippage on 1mm USDC I see 0bps slippage at ETH and +94bps slippage at Polygon. When pricing at 1.00 USDC I get -31bps slippage at ETH and -12bps slippage at Polygon.

Doesn't make sense that slippage would get better with larger trade sizes.

Also when trying to place trades on matcha, was seeing this same thing pop up in the quoted prices and was not allowed to place trades in the larger sizes for "insufficient matic balance", but definitely had the balance in the wallet

Using quote endpoint in api calls

```
# set 0x api endpoints
api_0x = {
    "ETH": "https://api.0x.org/",
    "POLY": "https://polygon.api.0x.org/",
}

# pricing using quote endpoint
p = "swap/v1/quote?"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `swap` endpoint is building you a swap to execute on the network. It performs cost based routing to get the best price. **It is not a general price API**.

Since Ethereum is expensive at the moment the `swap` endpoint is optimising for the best output. So the price on a $1 swap on Ethereum is going to appear strange as it is attempting to find you the cheapest liquidity source to execute that on, as you're effectively losing money due to costs.

In this example, `Uniswap_V2` is one of the cheapest sources to execute against, whereas `MakerPSM` is offering a 1:1 price of USDC to DAI. The difference is approximately 150,000 gas in execution costs. Which is ~$50 at the current time.

> "insufficient matic balance"

If you can provide me the full request for this we can take a closer look. When `takerAddress` is provided we give an accurate gas estimate and validate the user has the funds to pay for the transaction.